# React Native: filtering props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a basic component such as:

```
export default (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...props} style={styles.button}>
    {props.title && <Text style={styles.text}>{props.title}</Text>}
    {props.icon && <Icon name={props.icon} />}
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

I can then call it with `<Component title="Home" icon="home" />` for instance.

The problem is that passing `{...props}` to `TouchableOpacity` generate errors because it does not recognize title nor icon properly.
For instance:
`JSON value 'Home' of type NSString cannot be converted to...`

Is there a way to filter props so that I only pass valid ones for TouchableOpacity?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself “Why passing invalid props in the first place?”

Comment: Just pass the props you need?

Comment: So, I should just list the props I need? Quite heavy for wrapping native components :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Transferring Props](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html)

> Sometimes it's fragile and tedious to pass every property along. In that case you can use destructuring assignment with rest properties to extract a set of unknown properties.
>   List out all the properties that you would like to consume, followed by ...other.

```
var { checked, ...other } = props;
```

> This ensures that you pass down all the props EXCEPT the ones you're
>   consuming yourself.

```
function FancyCheckbox(props) {
  var { checked, ...other } = props;
  var fancyClass = checked ? 'FancyChecked' : 'FancyUnchecked';
  // `other` contains { onClick: console.log } but not the checked property
  return (
    <div {...other} className={fancyClass} />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <FancyCheckbox checked={true} onClick={console.log.bind(console)}>
    Hello world!
  </FancyCheckbox>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Paul Mcloughlin, I would recommend using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) along with a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring). You can destructure your props object directly in your function parameters like so:

```
({title, icon, ...remainingProps}) => (...)
```

This extracts the `title` and `icon` props from your props object and passes the rest as `remainingProps`.

Your complete component would be:

```
export default ({title, icon, ...remainingProps}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity {...remainingProps} style={styles.button}>
    {title && <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>}
    {icon && <Icon name={icon} />}
 </TouchableOpacity>
);
```